# Is it possible to convert integer to days and hours in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, time

I am using SQL Server 2014.

What I'm trying to do is add a new time to an old datetime.

I'm not even sure if it's possible but I thought I'd ask the experts.

So these are what my columns look like:

```
CurrentDate         | Hours | NewDate
2017-03-10 08:00:00 | 25    | ??
2017-01-01 10:00:00 | 27    | ??
```

What I want is the Hours to be converted to days and hours so it can be added to the CurrentDate to create a NewDate.

So the NewDate would be: 2017-03-11 09:00:00 because 25 hours equates to 1 day and 1 hour. And the second NewDate would be: 2017-01-02 01:00:00 because 27 equates to 1 day and 3 hours.

I actually don't think this is possible and there's a chance I might have to put the hours already converted into days and times but if that's the case, how would I write 25 hours? Would it be 00-00-01 01:00:00? And would 27 hours be 00-00-01 03:00:00 and then just add those values into CurrentDate?

Thanks! Feel free to tell me this has been asked before (I looked, but couldn't find anything as unique as this or maybe I didn't look hard enough) or if this can't be done.

Comment: what database engine are you using?

Comment: @Lamak SQL Server. Sorry, I will edit my post and add that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `DATEADD`, no need to convert the hours to days first:

```
SELECT CurrentDate, 
       Hours,
       DATEADD(HOUR,Hours,CurrentDate) NewDate
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: Oh wow, I just did it and it works. Thanks so much! I didn't know it was that simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
  select DATEADD(HOUR,25,'2017-03-10 08:00:00') -- 2017-03-11 09:00:00.000
  select DATEADD(HOUR,27,'2017-01-01 10:00:00') -- 2017-01-02 13:00:00.000
```